Unable to Debug macOS Action Extension: "Attach failed" Error
I'm encountering an issue while trying to debug a macOS Action Extension. I created a completely fresh project with an Action Extension target. When I select the Action Extension scheme and run it, choosing Finder as the host app (app to launch it in), I receive the following error:
Attach failed: Could not attach to pid : “647”. (Not allowed to attach to process. Look in the console messages (Console.app), near the debugserver entries, when the attach failed. The subsystem that denied the attach permission will likely have logged an informative message about why it was denied.)

This is in Console.app:
macOSTaskPolicy: (com.apple.debugserver) may not get the task control port of (Finder) (pid: 647): (Finder) is hardened, (Finder) doesn't have get-task-allow, (com.apple.debugserver) is a declared debugger(com.apple.debugserver) is not a declared read-only debugger.

I am pretty sure it worked before on my project that I am developing. It stopped working and now it doesn't even work on a fresh new project.
Any ideas? I tried cleaning derived data, restarting my mac, nothing helps.
As per the documentation it should work normally using the Build & Run button.

Edit Scheme -> Run -> Info, Is "Debug Executable" switched off?

You should attach to the pid of the extension as root. Xcode Main Menu => Debug => Attach to Process by Pid or Name. Be sure to select Debug Process as root before Attach

I made sure the "Debug executable" is switched off. Even though it doesn't make sense, since I want to debug...
It started working on the test fresh project (Run it, place a breakpoint, invoke the extension). The same approach is not working on my real project though. No matter if I run it or attach to process by PID or name. It fails with the error above.
Is there a way to completely clear the extension from my system so I can start fresh? It might seem there is a remnant of it. I don't have the container app installed. But I can still se the extension in the Quick Actions list.

Sometimes the Attach to process by PID works but when I try to step over or print something in the lldb it crashes. Other times it says a slightly different message "Could not attach".

If you choose the Finder as the host app then "Debug Executable" means "Debug Finder". Debugging the Finder is not allowed.

Yes, I made sure the "Debug executable" is off. It attaches but the debugger exits with code 9 whenever I try to po something or just step over lines.

I apologize for the delay in responding here. I am also tackling this issue on Apple Forums: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/756097?login=true&page=1#795215022. Right now I am in a state where I can attach the Action Extension to Finder (which is normal, I don't see how that would be not allowed, since it is a Quick Action extension, that runs in Finder). I am able to step over a couple of times but when I try to po, or step into/out, it crashes (lldb) saying "Couldn't communicate with a helper application'. It seems like a lldb bug.
